# How do I add the Nullable context in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I would like to add the global [nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) to my csproj in Unity. Unfortunately it is auto-generated and is constantly overwritten.

After reading some online suggestions, I've tried adding `-nullable:enable` to a file called `csc.rsp` at the root folder to no avail.

Running on MacOS 14, Unity 2023.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to enable it globally? it's possible to define a nullable variable anywhere in c#

just use "?" at the end of the definition of the variable.

for example:

```
int? vv=null;
float? ff=null;
if(vv==null)
 vv.value=1;
else
 vv.value=2;
```

Comment: That is not the nullable reference context. Try `string?` or `MyClass?`